# I need MySQL query that search name of hospital using MySQL 5.0

Tags: mysql, node.js

When I search for “Kaiser Fresno” nothing shows up, but when I search just “Kaiser” the Fresno option is halfway down the list. Ideally if someone searches “Kaiser Fresno” the “Kaiser FND Hosp - Fresno” should populate even though it’s not an exact match.

```
search key => “Kaiser Fresno”
possible output => “Kaiser FND Hosp - Fresno”
```

This is the query I am using for the finding the results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM hospitals 
WHERE name LIKE "%Kaiser Fresno%"
```

Please give the possible solution bases on MySQL 5.0

Comment: Behold the [MySQL Full-Text Search Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: It's also time to update from 5.0 which is, at this point, a museum relic. It's from 2005. There are people older than it posting on this site.

Comment: I dont think this will work on MySQL 5.0

Comment: It does have MyISAM full-text indexes, so if you're already using those types of tables at least you can use that, but they're honestly extremely brittle and a huge liability in any deployment. The truth is you really should make it a priority to update.

Comment: I will add to the chorus saying "update now." Old MySql versions are deprecated partly for security reasons. Under the US patient privacy laws (HIPAA and ARRA-2009) it's a really bad idea -- a felony offense -- to willfully ignore information security problems that lead to disclosure of private patient data.

Answer (score 1):

Break it into two

```
 SELECT * FROM hospitals WHERE name LIKE "%Kaiser%" OR name LIKE '%Fresno%'
```

Comment: I am geting the search key from the user I don't know what user will enter in search key, may be there is more than two words.

Comment: You can construct the search string programmatically based on what the user enters.

Comment: yes, but it's manual query builing I know that, I want any suggestion that do so using inbuild mechanism